# create trigger to save CONSTRAINTs changes on tables in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, constraints

I want to create table to save all CONSTRAINTs changes in my oracle database,
so i have created this table(table name , constraint name , date , mode like [insert|update|delete] )

```
CREATE TABLE CONS
(
  C_ID NUMBER NOT NULL 
, C_NAME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL 
, T_NAME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL 
, EXE_DATE  DATE  NOT NULL 
, MODE VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL 
);
```

the problem was by insert data,

I was thinking of creating trigger on [user_cons_columns](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1035.htm#i1575870) after insert or update or delete,

but I found that [user_cons_columns](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1035.htm#i1575870) is a view  and i can't create trigger on it,

so how can I do this work?

or what is the tables that I can create trigger on it to do this???

thanks .......

Comment: The correct way to do this would be to have your DDL scripts managed in a source control repository.

Answer (score 0):

User_Cons_Columns is metadata view in oracle and you can not use it for monitoring constraint changes.

I think, You can use this metadata view :

```
SELECT *
FROM  ALL_CONSTRAINTS T
```

It shows which constraint has changed by LAST_CHANGE Column and other data that you can use them.

Comment: the same problem 
"cannot create this trigger type on views"

Comment: You do not need to create trigger. The ALL_CONSTRAINTS view gives you all you need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if we can create DML `TRIGGER`s on data dictionary tables in Oracle, but that sounds like a bad idea.

My suggestion to you would be to create a [DDL Trigger](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ddl_triggers.htm)  on the `ALTER` event

Firstly, as a one time activity, you could store all the  available constraints   in your `CONS` table.

Then in your `trigger`, you could use these conditions to check if a table and  column was altered.

```
if (ora_sysevent = 'ALTER' and
ora_dict_obj_type = 'TABLE')
  then alter_column := 
ora_is_alter_column('FOO');
end if;
```

You could then query the `user_cons_columns` , `ALL_CONSTRAINTS` and `CONS`  - whichever you find is relevant to store your data - to find if a new constraint was added or not. If it was indeed added or modified, make an entry into `CONS` or else update it ( using `MERGE` statement )

Comment: @MohammedNosirat : I think if you do not need the information to be updated in real time, you could also run a program everyday which just does the comparison with the entries in your table `cons` and the data dictionary entry,  and merge the entries by capturing the new/modified ones.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you can't create that type of a trigger on USER_CONS_COLUMNS:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_myucc
  2  before insert
  3  on user_cons_columns
  4  begin
  5   null;
  6  end;
  7  /
create or replace trigger trg_myucc
                          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-25001: cannot create this trigger type on this type of view
```

Why wouldn't we try **INSTEAD OF TRIGGER**?

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_myucc
  2  instead of insert
  3  on user_cons_columns
  4  for each row
  5  begin
  6    null;
  7  end;
  8  /
on user_cons_columns
   *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

OK, that won't work either. But, what prevents us on creating a view upon a view, and then create INSTEAD OF trigger on that newly created view?

```
SQL> create or replace view my_ucc as select * from user_cons_columns;

View created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_myucc
  2  instead of insert
  3  on my_ucc
  4  for each row
  5  begin
  6    null;
  7  end;
  8  /

Trigger created.
```

Fine; now you have a way to do what you're supposed to do. More about triggers [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#LNPLS020).